# How to send a cookie along with HttpGet in Java

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I am trying to send a cookie along with my HttpGet request, but everytime I try I havent been able to successfully send it.   I also tried to modify the headers directly, here is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  

CookieStore store = new BasicCookieStore();
store.addCookie(MyCookieStorageClass.getCookie());
httpClient.setCookieStore(store);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost/);     

try {
    // Execute HTTP Get Request  
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);  
    String responseData = ResponseHandler.getResponseBody(response);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct implementation for the HttpClient 4.0.1, I had just had not been getting the correct cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the correct implementation for the HttpClient 4.0.1, I had just had not been getting the correct cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyCookieStorageClass.getCookie()` method do return a Cookie with correct domain and path attribute?