# Android Confusion

Tags: php, android, session

I am new to android and i always search for same problem that i face but this time i am totaly confused.

I have scenario that when user send login credential to phpwebservice and after successful login session starts from phpwebservice(server side) where is that session stored in Android? Extract all the code but i failed to locate my sessions variables ..

i saw many post that talk about sharedpresferences and cookie manager .. The confusion is that i am bit lost here .. What is cookiemanager and what is that used for ..? I debugged my code and saw PHPSESSID exists in cookiemanager object.

how will this PHPSESSID will help me to use other webservices? May i need to send the PHPSESSID in http header to fetch webservices? what about the sessions that was started?

Please guys help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the session is not stored on the client. PHP will set a cookie with `PHPSESSID` so that it can identify the session when you make another request.

You don't provide an example of what you are doing but if you send the cookies that you are supplied then the session will be maintained.

See [PHP Session Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Comment: OK but dont laugh on my next question ...
will phpwebservice identify the session of the user? .. if user call the service and what if session is not created and user call the service ?

Comment: If you pass the cookie with the session id then PHP will use that session. If you do not pass the session id then it will be the same as a new session being created.

Comment: do you mean sessionid = PHPSESSID ?
and passing cookie through (httpcontext || httpheader)?
and on phpwebservice what i have to define for the session?

Comment: Yes PHPSESSID is the PHP session id. Passing cookies depend on your code and the library you use. See here for sending cookies back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383367/how-to-send-a-cookie-along-with-httpget-in-java

Comment: thank you jim for helping me

Answer (score 0):

What I do is after authentication with a backend system, I keep an access token (life Facebook does) and use it everytime to call the backend, that always works and its secure enough.

Comment: Thanks for the information i will search for this too.